# How to drop the voltage of a power supply?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, resistors, voltage-regulator

I have a DC power supply which outputs 21V 2.2A.

I want to use it to charge a car battery so I need to get the voltage down to 14V.

I have a 3.9Ohm 100W resistor but am am I correct that that would draw around 5A.

What resistor should I use to drop the voltage to 14V?

Comment: You cannot and should not charge a car battery this way. The voltage is too high (more than 13.8 V) so you'll **overcharge** the car battery and **damage it**. The resistor will not limit the voltage to 14 V when the battery is full. Also **explosive gasses** could escape. Car battery chargers are cheap, just get one of those.

Comment: Resistors don't work that way. At the very least you need a voltage regulator, which could be a single component or a circuit of multiple components (some of which may be resistors). But a single resistor will **not** do what you want.

Comment: (21-12)/2A=4.5 Ohm.  (21-11.5V)/3.9 = 2.43 A  . overcurrent on low battery, manual cuttoff needs monitor in real-time.

Comment: Try to limit the charge current by connecting a car lamp or a combination of lamps between the power supply and the battery. For example, try with two 21 W lamps in parallel or two 60 W in series... or something else (as a bonus you will also have free lighting:) You can make simple calculations but keep in mind that the lamp resistance is nonlinear (it increases with temperature). I have done it many times in the past when I was dealing with cars... and not once did a battery explode... You can enlarge this idea with some else useful ballast load (e.g. a fan:)

Comment: I'm with @Bimpelrekkie.   This is NOT a suitable application for a resistor, don't even try it.  Or if you do, wear a full hazmat suit and eye protection so the battery acid doesn't permanently disfigure you.     Dude, you can literally buy a "real" battery charger for like $10.   Sometimes you just gotta suck it up and take the pre-engineered solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of the setup is wrong,

A single resistor will not help, all that can achieve is current limiting which would be I = V/R = 21V / 3.9R = 5.4A @ 21V. This would not change the voltage in the slightest.

You would need to create a voltage divider to drop the voltage, to do this you would need something like a 3.9R (R1) & ~6R (R2) to get around ~12.7V (Vout) with Vin @ 21V. This is not recommended as the battery will act as a load and will affect the division based on its internal resistance. See the image below,
[image]

To do this correctly you would need a regulator to step down the voltage from 21V to 14V, by the time you get ones of these you would probably be better off buying a Car Battery Charger. In the UK it looks like something dirt cheap costs around £20 and looks like this.
[image]

Comment: *This would not change the voltage in the slightest* - don't be too general about this. I know what you mean but you need to spell it out when connected to the battery.

Comment: Well maybe slightly FOXSUR 12V 5A Pulse Repair Charger

Comment: Good point Andy, that was a bit to generalised. Obviously, I was describing the scenario before the described setup is connected to a battery. 21V through the 3.9R resistor not connected would measure as 21V. The moment you connect the other end of the 3.9R Resistor you are introducing a new resistance to the circuit (Quick google suggests that car batteries are around 1R) so now you would have R1 3.9R & R2 1R giving you in theory 4.285V over R2. Regardless of my abbreviated description this is not the solution.

Comment: car battery 1R? (not)  if CCA = 500A at 7.5V then ESR=<0.01R = (12.5-7.5)/500, the FOXsur is a cheap solution to desulphation if done shortly after detected or as preventive in parallel with alternator. 5A is a narrow pulse at a rate which can breakdown lead sulphate crystals that raise ESR..